# Animating the scrollbar as a progressbar

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want my scrollbar to be like a progressbar, and to prevent any weird lag issues, I decided to do that by animating the scrollbar. I made an animation that changes the size property of the scrollbar, but despite of the size value actually changing, the scrollbar remains visually the same.

After looking in the scrollbar.cs script I found "private void UpdateVisuals()", that would do the trick, but it's private, and I don't really know how to access it from animation or other script. Any ideas?

Comment: If possible, use sliders instead, they are not laggy and super easy to make into a progress bar

Comment: @MrDiamond Wow, it works a lot better with slider, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just using a slider is a better idea, it changes dynamically

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).